# How to start a phone call in background android

Tags: android, android-activity, backgroundworker, phone-call, ussd

I'm looking for a way to start a phone call to a USSD code example *123# but I want to get the response in the background so I have to start this phone call in the background to prevent the loading section how can I do that?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961745/i-there-a-way-to-run-an-interactive-ussd-session-and-hide-the-session-behind-a-l/68148632#68148632) which has an probable answer